# Template System With Laravel

Tags: php, templates, laravel

i try to make a template system with laravel and php

// controller file

```
$settigs=json_decode(Settings::find(1));
return View::make('home',array('my_dynamic_template_folder'=>$settigs->theme_folder));
```

//view file

```
@extends(' (my template folder) . main ')
```

i want to make like this

```
@extends('{{$my_dynamic_template_folder}}.main')
```

but i have a error like this `View [{{$site_theme}}.main] not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably will work if you:

```
@extends($my_dynamic_template_folder.'.main')
```

Comment: That'll definitely work, providing that `$my_dynamic_template_folder` is set, and it's an actual directory.